# Calculating shortest distance between two points on water, avoiding land?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

Can someone explain to me (in beginner's terms) how to calculate the distance between two points that are on water, avoiding land?

For example, these points are inshore in a bay, so I don't want the path to go over any of the bends in the coastline.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Spatial Analyst, take a polygon that represents your water and convert it to a raster. Then you can use the "Cost Path" tool. If your only constraint is that you have to stay in the water, just make all the water cells have value of 1 when you create the raster. The land cells should have a value of NODATA, and I'm pretty sure the cost path will not be allowed to go through those cells. (If I'm wrong, then you'll want a raster where the water cell value is 1 and the land is some very large number.)

I can't think of a way to do it without Spatial Analyst.